# Python - When number is equal to or above question

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple script that will give a random number between 1 and 100 and print out either "you win" or "you lose" based on the result. When testing for the specific number like `== 1` it works fine, but when replacing it with `<=` it gives me this error: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'`

Here is my code:

```
import random

number = print(random.randint(1, 100))
if number <= 20:
    print("you win")
else:
    print("you lose")
```

Comment: `print` returns `None`. so `number` is `None`, when you do `number = print(random.randint(1, 100))` This wasn't working the way you desired in the first place.

Comment: What do/don't you understand from that error message?

Comment: do not assign a variable to the value of `print()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print` always returns `None`, so don't assign the return value of `print` to `number`. Do it in two steps:

```
import random

number = random.randint(1, 100)
print(number)
if number <= 20:
    print("you win")
else:
    print("you lose")
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Didn't notice that but i accepted your answer now :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have to first store the variable you get from the random:

```
number = random.randint(1, 100)
```

You can they print it, and compare it in your "if":

```
print(number)
if number <= 20:
    ...
```

The print function does not return the variable you want.